# Activity lifecycle - array was erased

Tags: android, listadapter, activity-lifecycle

I have a problem with Activity life cycle. In my server communication Activity I am downloading the list of items from the server and then setting up the Adapter for the ListView.

Everything is fine but if I press Home button on this screen and after some while (e.g. 3 hours or more) return back to the screen via application manager, application crashes. The problem is in the onTextChanged() method (which is usefull for searching via EditText) where I am calling the setAdapter() method again. There is nullPointerException because my array was somehow erased.

Why is the onTextChanged() method called again during restoring? And why was the array erased?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: put your code here you shuould be use array on resume() method.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the activity lifecycle diagram on:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Your Activity goes to Pause state after you press Home.
And after 3hrs or even a shorter time,it may be killed by system for resource management.
So it need to be created again on next launch.

I think you should add code to handle `onDestroy()` and `onStop()`.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I can finish the activity when it is restarted after this long delay. What do you think? Or what to do in onDestroy or in onStop method? Actually, why is onTextChanged method called?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the data the same way you did originally, by overriding the

```
onResume()
```

method, checking if the data is existent or not beforehand.